# How to define an element with infinite max occurs

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to make an xml schema where the root can have none, or multiple times an element. But I only know how to make elements that have a fixed max occur amout, but I want to have infinite max occurs, so that any amount is possible.

I only know how to make a fixed amount of min and max occurs, and I know how to make these in a fixed or arbitrary order. But how do I do this, so that I can, e.g. have it like this:

```
<root>
    <foo />
    <bar />
    <foo />
    <bar />

    <!-- ... -->
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XSD-1.0 schema should satisfy your needs. It uses the `xs:all` element as child of the `xs:complexType` to indicate that either the `foo` element or the `bar` element can occur 0 times to infinite times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />                                                  
                <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />                                                  
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```